# Creating a mail with attachment in Outlook and displaying it

Tags: delphi, outlook, mailing

I want to create a mail with attachment in Outlook and display it before sending it, but I think I have tried almost every sample I have found on the net without any luck.
I could use Indy, but I would very much like to use Outlook to be sure that the mail is proper because it is for business use.

Any input for a function that takes Address, subject, message and attachment as parameters and then displays the message in Outlook before sending it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [MailItem.Display Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861853.aspx).

```
uses
  comobj;

..

procedure DisplayMail(Address, Subject, Body: string; Attachment: TFileName);
var
  Outlook: OleVariant;
  Mail: Variant;
const
  olMailItem = $00000000;
begin
  try
    Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  except
    Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  end;
  Mail := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem);
  Mail.To := Address;
  Mail.Subject := Subject;
  Mail.Body := Body;
  if Attachment <> '' then
    Mail.Attachments.Add(Attachment);
  Mail.Display;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DisplayMail('mailaddress', 'subject', 'message', 'attachmentfile');
end;
```

Comment: I am not sure yet what I have been doing wrong because it is pretty much the same code as I have been using but with no luck.
Your code on the other hand works.
I am wondering if it has something to do with the fact that I have been using Outlook_TLB - but I can't see what this should do.

Do you know if it is possible to add Request read receipt and delivery receipt to the code?

Comment: For receipt read request check the [`ReadReceiptRequested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865400.aspx) property and use it as `Mail.ReadReceiptRequested := True;`

Comment: .. and `OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested` propety.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz  I am still struggling with this system :-) I am used to a site here in Denmark that is a bit simpler/easier to use.
But I think I found out how to accept the answer.

Now I am working on expandig the mail send to use a specific account. This is quite easy in VBA.